# exclude tags with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the contents of a html table with beautifulsoup.
when I get to the level of the cell I need to get only the values that are not between the strike parameter

```
<td>
<strike>$0.45</strike><br/>
                       $0.41
                     </td>
```

so in the case above I would like to return only $0.41. I am using data.get_text() but I do not know how to filter out the $0.45
any ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

All the solutions above will work. Adding one more method: **`extract()`**

From the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract):

> `PageElement.extract()` removes a tag or string from the tree. It returns the tag or string that was extracted.

You can use it like this (added one more `<td>` tag to show how it can be used in a loop):

```
html = '''
<td>
    <strike>
        $0.45
    </strike>
    <br/>
    $0.41
</td>
<td>
    <strike>
        $0.12
    </strike>
    <br/>
    $0.14
</td>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for td in soup.find_all('td'):
    td.strike.extract()
    print(td.text.strip())
```

Output:

```
$0.41
$0.14
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look at all `NavigableString` children of the TD tag and ignore all other elements:

```
textData = ''.join(x for x in soup.find('td').children \
                   if isinstance(x, bs4.element.NavigableString)).strip()
#'$0.41'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same in several ways. Here is one such way:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content="""
<td>
<strike>$0.45</strike><br/>
                       $0.41
                     </td>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")
item = soup.find("td").contents[-1].strip()
print(item)
```

Output:

```
$0.41
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the following way

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

h = '''
<td>
<strike>$0.45</strike><br/>
                       $0.41
                                            </td>
'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(h, 'lxml')

a = soup.find('td').get_text()

print(a.split('\n')[2].strip())
```

Split it with Enter and delete both spaces.